# Visio automation: get process ID

Tags: vbscript, automation, ole, visio

I'm running Visio using automation and I'm having trouble getting the process ID of the Visio process to check when its complete. Here's my VB script:

```
Set visio = CreateObject("Visio.InvisibleApp")
Wscript.Echo visio.ProcessID    
Set document = visio.Documents.OpenEx("somefile.vsd", &H88)
document.ExportAsFixedFormat 1, "somefile.pdf", 1, 0
visio.Quit
```

and running it with `cscript // nologo`.

The problem is that `visio.ProcessID` returns a number that isn't the actual Windows process ID (e.g. 6613 when the actual process ID is 8146). The cscript host seems to finish before the Visio process exits causing problems cleaning up temp files.

Here is the Visio reference notes for:

- [ProcessID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms426216%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Quit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196022%28v=office.12%29)

So the question is: how can I get the Visio process ID or detect when it has properly exited?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem and solve it in very stupid wat .I've called pslist -t (part of sysinternals instruments) and serched for name process under wshost.exe with counting spaces to see if it's a child process.If you can find another way - it's a way too :)

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed this in the help for Visio.Application.ProcessID:

"The value returned by ProcessID is not the same as the Windows Process ID of the current Visio instance."

So I guess these are just so you can distinguish between multiple instances of Visio.

There are also Visio.Application.WindowHandle32 and Visio.Application.WindowHandle, which might be helpful, although maybe not so much for an invisible app instance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see how this id would help you. I suspect you get an error in visio. Have you tried with

```
on error resume next
```

and after each line that could give an error

```
if err.number <> 0 then
  wscript.echo err.description
  err.clear
end if
```

There seems to be an issue if you omit parameters, so use them all.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms409271(v=office.12).aspx for the values.
Before quiting use `document.saved = true`, you could check first if the result file exists.

EDIT: check if a process is running, could be you have to adapt the name of the service (check your téaskmanager)

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
  If lcase(Process.Name) = "visio.exe" then
    wscript.echo "visio still running"
    wscript.quit
  End If
next
wscript.echo "visio no longer running"
```

EDIT2: to get the processid of the active visio app (If more than one Visio instance is running, GetObject returns the active instance. When a program is run as an add-on or by double-clicking a shape, the active instance is the one that the program was run from. Otherwise, it is the instance that was most recently run or brought to the front. If no Visio instance is running, GetObject causes an error)
cfr http://webmail.vh.com.tw/Microsoft/Developing%20Microsoft%20Visio%20Solutions/27.htm

```
set appObj = GetObject(, "visio.application")
if appObj Is Nothing Then
  wscript.echo "There is no active Visio."
else
  wscript.echo "ProcessID: " & appObj.ProcessID
end if
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error in the vbscript; I just need to know when the Visio process exits. At the moment there is a race condition between `visio.quit` and when it actually exits.

Comment: i added a sample script how to check if a process is still running, place it in a loop and when the service is stopped do the cleanup and close

Comment: The thing is that the conversion to PDF is happening in more than one process at a time so there could be another Visio process active on the system when I'm trying to clean up the current one. That's why I'm keen to get the process ID in the vbscript.